# why the results of response.xpath('//html') differs than response.body?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, response

I'm trying to parse this page using scrapy
http://mobileshop.ae/one-x

I need to extract the links of the products.
The problem is the links are available in the response.body result, but no available if you try response.xpath('//body').extract()

the results of response.body and response.xpath('//body') are different.

```
>>> body = response.body
>>> body_2 = response.xpath('//html').extract()[0]
>>> len(body)
238731
>>> len(body_2)
67520
```

same short result for response.xpath('.').extract()[0]

is there any idea why this happens, and how can I extract the data needed ?

Comment: It seems the problem is due to invalid HTML markup on that page -- it has several tags that were not closed (check it with http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: how do you think I should fix this ? do you recommend a library that could fix that invalid html ?

Comment: So, it turns out that lxml has a way around this -- lemme add a proper answer.

Comment: Just a note: checking only the sizes is probably not the more effective way to see the differences, since lxml will do some content cleanup anyway. A better way to expose the problem is to show the difference between: ``re.findall('<h4.+', response.body)`` and ``re.findall('<h4.+', response.selector.extract())``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the issue here is a lot of mal-formed content in that page, including several unclosed tags. One way to solve this problem is to use [lxml's soupparser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) to parse the mal-formed content (using BeautifulSoup under the covers) and build a Scrapy Selector with it.

Example session with `scrapy shell http://mobileshop.ae/one-x`:

```
>>> from lxml.html import soupparser
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(_root=soupparser.fromstring(response.body))
>>> sel.xpath('//h4[@class="name"]/a').extract()
[u'<a href="http://mobileshop.ae/one-x/htc-one-x-16gb-gray">HTC One X 3G 16GB Grey</a>',
 u'<a href="http://mobileshop.ae/one-x/htc-one-x-16gb-white">HTC One X 3G 16GB White</a>',
 u'<a href="http://mobileshop.ae/one-x/htc-one-x-32gb-gray">HTC One X 3G 32GB Grey</a>',
 u'<a href="http://mobileshop.ae/one-x/htc-one-x-32gb-white">HTC One X 3G 32GB White</a>']
```

Note that using the BeautifulSoup parser is a lot slower than lxml's default parser. You probably want to do this only in the places where it's really needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.xpath("//body")` returns [body of 'html' element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp) contained in response, while `response.body` returns body [(or message-body)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3) of whole HTTP response (so all html in response including head & body elements).

`Response.xpath("//body")` is actually shortcut that converts body of HTTP response into Selector object that can be navigated with xpaths.

Links that you need are contained in html element body, they cannot really be anywhere else, I'm not sure why you suggest that they are not there. `response.xpath("//body//a/@href")` will give you all links on page, you probably need to create proper xpath that will select only those links you need.

The length of `response.xpath("//body")` that you mention in your example results from the fact that your first example `len(response.xpath('//body').extract())` returns the number of body elements in html document, `response.xpath.extract()` returns list of elements matching xpath. There is only one body in document. In your second example  `len(response.xpath('//body')).extract()[0])` you are actually getting body element as string, and you are getting length of string (number of characters contained in body). `len(response.body)` also gives you number of characters in whole HTTP response, the number is higher most likely because html HEAD contains lots of scripts and stylesheets, that are not present in HTML body.

Comment: I'm sorry, there were something that needed to be edited in question, I meant the difference between response.body and response.xpath('//html'), it's supposed to be the same, both contains the head element.
Although this xpath with the links I need : response.xpath('//h4[@class="name"]/a').extract() 
is available on response.body, but the links aren't present in response.xpath('//html')

Comment: Pawel, the problem is that the page has invalid HTML (several unclosed tags), it seems that is causing lxml to drop some content.

Comment: aha! that was not clear from first version of question. OP edited question and his code sample :) previously he was selecting xpath("//body") now he selects "//html".